# Jquery autocomplete on more than One cell of a table

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, cells

I have a HTML table with two cells to seek Autocomplete Inputs:
The HTML is as follows

```js
      $('#address1').focus(function() {
        $.ajax({  
        url:"../phpAssets/StnList.php",  
        method:"POST",      
        success:function(data){
           availableStns =  jQuery.parseJSON(new Array(data));
        window.alert(data);
        $('#address1').autocomplete({
               source: availableStns
        });
        }
       });
      });  //The Line where the Browser throws error
      
     $('#fileRef').focus(function() {
     var selectedSection = $('#section option:selected');
        var selsec = selectedSection.val();
        $.ajax({  
       url:"../phpAssets/fileRefList.php",   
       method:"POST",       
       data:{selsec:selsec},       
       success:function(data){ 
        availableFileRefs =  jQuery.parseJSON(new Array(data)); 
       $('#fileRef').autocomplete({ 
              source: availableFileRefs 
       }); 
       } 
      }); 
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
       <thead>   
      <tr>   
       <th scope="col" style="width: 200px;">File Reference</th>   
       <th scope="col">Address</th>   
      </tr>   
       </thead>   
       <tbody>   
      <tr>   
       <td><input name ="fileRef" id="fileRef" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="on"></td>   
         <td name ="address1" id="address1"><input name ="address1" id="address1" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="on"></td>   
        </td>   
        </tr>   
       </tbody>   
</table>
```

The code is Syntactically correct but the Browser is throwing following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

This is at the line where the first .focus() function ends. Tried my best but couldn't understand the reason.

Comment: the browser throws the error when, you type something in the input?

Comment: No sir, Immediately on page loading and then all scripts halt.

Comment: Which version of JQuery are you using ? jQuery.parseJSON is deprecated since 3.0; use JSON.parse instead

Comment: I am using jQuery-UI 1.12.1 and Jquery 1.12.1 but that is not the point of error.

Comment: and the code you posted doesn't have errors.

Comment: Yes sir. I checked the code using http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html which reports that the js `Code is syntactically valid.`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/op9dqooL/

Comment: Ram Segev, Your code Improvement does not solve the problem. The error remains. Can the Code Improvement be undone.

Answer (score 0):

I dunna what changes happened. I just copied the relevant code portion to another .php and tested it and copied it back to main project file. The Stuff is working now. Here is the (amended, if I may say) script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd M y' });
  });

  $('#address1').focus(function() {
    $.ajax({  
            url:"../phpAssets/StnList.php",  
            method:"POST",      
            success:function(data){
                availableStns =  jQuery.parseJSON(new Array(data));
                $('#address1').autocomplete({
                source: availableStns
                });
            }
            });
  });  //The Line where the Browser throws error

 $('#fileRef').focus(function() {
    var selectedSection = $('#section option:selected');
    var selsec = selectedSection.val();
    $.ajax({  
        url:"../phpAssets/fileRefList.php",     
        method:"POST",          
        data:{selsec:selsec},       
        success:function(data){ 

            availableFileRefs =  jQuery.parseJSON(new Array(data)); 
            $('#fileRef').autocomplete({    
              source: availableFileRefs 
            }); 
        }   
        }); 
  });
</script>
```